# "Stringernal error" when requesting a Native Ad on Huawei Quick-App

Tags: ads, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-ads

I'm following this tutorial '[How can i integrate Huawei Ads into a HWAWEI HTML5 Quick Game] https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topic/0203442495128230052?fid=0101187876626530001' by a Huawei developer. But every time I request an ad, the onError callback fires with this result: {"errCode":1003,"errMsg":"Stringernal error."}. So far, I’ve tried running on a device, on emulator, tried to set the minPlatformVersion on manifest, and made sure I have the "service.ad" on the manifest. Also tried to create my own ad unit and put the ID on the code.

Does anyone know what this error means? Thanks

Comment: Can you pls provide more logs to help us locate this issue? Use the adb command to obtain log : adb pull /sdcard/Android/data/com.huawei.hwid/files/Log/HiAdKitLog.log ./

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the ad test ID you’re using is valid. Here’s the documentation for the 1003 error code link. You can also find more information in the official documentation [link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-References-V1/error-codes-0000001072035357-V1).

[image]